# Remove/Delete app from App Directory in #yammer

Tags: yammer

One of former employee developed and deployed an app into Yammer global App Directory. This app is no longer required and please let me know, how to remove/delete the app from global App Directory in Yammer?

Thanks,
Harsha

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to file a Support case to get the app disabled or re-assigned to a service account.